# Using result of let in where clause LinQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am using Linq To SQL to get data from from data tables. I want to use the result of a let statement in a where clause.

eg:-

```
from t1 in table1
      join t2 in table2
      on t1.field1 equals t2.field2
      let calculatedValue = t2.val1 + t2.val2
      join t3 in table3
      on t2.somefield equals t3.somefield
      into t3Grp
      from subt3 in t3Grp.DefaultIfEmpty()
      [select the row in table3 with where table3.someValue < calculatedValue]
```

The proble I face in calculatedValue is not accessible in `.Where()` clause of table3. I want fully left join output( ie; even if there is no row in table3 having `someValue < calculatedValue` i want that row in the output. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
from t1 in table1
  join t2 in table2
  on t1.field1 equals t2.field2
  let calculatedValue = t2.val1 + t2.val2
  join t3 in table3.where(item => item.someValue < calculatedValue)
  on t2.somefield equals t3.somefield
  into t3Grp
  from subt3 in t3Grp.DefaultIfEmpty()
  select new
  {
    val1= table3.val1,
    val2 = table3.val2,
    .
    .
    .
  }
```

Comment: I think the left join behaviour will be lost unless the where condition is specified as "join t3 in table.Where(i=>i.someValue < calculatedValue)..

Comment: Hi, Thank you all for your help. Finally i fixed the issue by using the where clause on the result on DefaultIfEmpty..Something like join t2 with t3 from t3Group.DefaultIfEmpty().Where(i=>i == null ? i.someValue == null : i.someValue < calculatedValue). Using this, the row is not lost even if no matching value if found in table3.

Answer (score -1):

Can you do this by restricting `t3Grp` in your final `select`, e.g.

```
from t1 in table1
join t2 in table2
on t1.field1 equals t2.field2
let calculatedValue = t2.val1 + t2.val2
join t3 in table3
on t2.somefield equals t3.somefield
into t3Grp
from subt3 in t3Grp.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { t1, t2, t3Grp = t3Grp.Where(t3 => t3.someValue < calculatedValue) }
```

The value is *in scope* there, I'm just not sure of the exact projection you want.